# How does Caffe Convolution Layer's Num of Outputs Work with Kernel and Stride Sizes?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, convolution

Perhaps a noob question, but after reading the caffe.proto file on Github, I cannot reconcile how two (really three) specs for the convolution layer co-exist:

1. Number of outputs;
2. Kernel size and stride.

Don't the kernel size and stride necessarily dictate a convolution layer's number of outputs?  I see in the .proto file that the number of outputs is an optional spec, which leads me to believe that the number of outputs can be user-defined rather than a derived function of kernel size and stride.  Is this true?  If yes, for what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

No. `num_output` refers to the number of channels of the output whereas `kernel_size`, `pad`,`stride` are used to calculate size of each channel.

Answer (score 1):

Convolution layers takes in volumes as input and output. The output volume depends on:-

```
1. Kernel size
2. Kernel stride
3. padding 
4. No of kernels (filters)
```

For example:- if input volume is 32x32x3 and convolution layer has 10 `(no of kernels)` 5x5 `(kernel size)` filters with `stride` 1 and `pad` 2 then output size spatially would be:-

```
input_size+pad*2-kernel_size/stride+1
```

(32+2*2-5)/1+1 = 32
therefore spatially the size would be 32x32
And the depth of output is always equal to No of kernels. i.e. 10
hence output volume will be 32x32x10

Comment: Ahh.  I fundamentally misunderstood what the No. of Outputs spec was.  Makes sense.